# Who pays for the destruction of an insured car in GTA Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

In *GTA Online*, I have heard that the players that blow up your PV (personal vehicle) will have to pay for your insurance. But in my case, when other players blow up my PV, I have to pay for it. Is this a glitch and if so how do I fix it?

Answer (score 9):

Who pays the insurance claim changes depending on the person that destroyed the vehicle and where it was. The cost of the insurance claim changes based on the total price of the vehicle including modifications:

- For vehicles under GTA$100.000, is the 10% of the total cost
- For vehicles over GTA$100.000, it is always GTA$10.000

A couple of examples showing who pays and what price:

- If you are playing in PC, the insurance claim is free for the vehicle owner, no matter who destroyed it

  - This was done by Rockstar Games to prevent an exploit that allowed cheaters with mod menus to drain other player's bank accounts by impersonating them ([here is an example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qfC0knSehFA))
- If your vehicle is destroyed in a mission, the insurance claim is free

  - Player A blows up the Armored Kuruma of Player B during [Pacific Standard - Convoy](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Pacific_Standard_-_Convoy). Because it was during a mission, neither Player A or Player B pays for the insurance. Player B can claim a new vehicle for free.
- If a player destroyed your vehicle in freeroam, that player pays the insurance

  - Player A blows up Player's B stock T20. Because it costs more than GTA$100.000 (GTA$2.200.000), the insurance cost is reduced to GTA$10.000. Player A pays GTA$10.000.

    - If he does not has the GTA$10.000, the owner needs to pay the rest of the money missing from those 10k.
- If you destroyed your own vehicle directly in freeroam, you pay the insurance

  - Player A blows up his own Buzzard. Because he was the direct cause of the destruction of the vehicle, he needs to pay the GTA$10.000 of the insurance (the Buzzard costs GTA$1.750.000).

Comment: This may answer the question - if players who destroyed user74165's vehicle didn't have enough money to pay the entire insurance, then he would have had to pay. Unfortunately in this case, there isn't anything user74165 can do except to avoid having his vehicle destroyed

Comment: Are there differences between console & PC, and enhanced & non-enhanced versions? A [discussion here \(reddit gtaonline subreddit\)](https://www.reddit.com/r/gtaonline/comments/ff4ite/i_hate_ppl_who_use_the_oppressor_to_grief_others/fjw233d/?context=99) states that the insurance bill could be as high as $20K in the console version.

Comment: I have destroyed high-end cars on PS3 and PS4 and is always GTA$10.000. On PC, Xbox One, Xbox 360, PS3 and PS4 is the same on the current update.

Comment: I was wrong. On PC nobody pays the insurance, no matter who destroyed the vehicle. There was (is?) an exploit that allowed cheaters with mod menus to drain money from other users by doing an "insurance fraud" that impersonates the other player and destroys cars remotely. There is some information in the [Claims section of the Mors Mutual Insurance wiki article](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Mors_Mutual_Insurance#Claims). I updated the answer with this info.

Comment: What happens when someone blows up my vehicle but they don't have money and I also don't have money?

Comment: In Freemode you pay, in Missions nobody pays.

Comment: Ok but another player in a plane directly blew up my car with rockets and i had to pay the full 20k as if i had blown it up myself. (PS4 Toreador)

Answer (score 3):

This used to be the case. At least last I played (like 2 months when it GTA Online first came out). If someone used a rocket, C4, or other means of directly destroying my vehicle, they had to pay for it. There have been plenty of times this has happened, especially when all those rich kids got tanks...

However it looks like now that has changed. Testing it with a rocket, C4, and a tank, someone blows up my Adder and now I'm the one paying $12,500.

Answer (score 2):

People now abuse the system by letting themselves run out of money then start blowing the hell out of cars.

If you do not have the money for the insurance, you will pay as much as you have, i.e.:

1. You have **$200.00** in your wallet + bank account;
2. You blow up my Adder;
3. You pay **$200.00**;
4. I pay the other **$12.300**.

And that's one of the ways some people just end up getting away with blowing up our vehicles.

Answer (score 1):

If the player blows up your car they pay the insurance fee. If they only have 1000$, and your insurance fee is 27,500(t20 supercar). They pay 1000$ because thats all they have. I have never had to pay the difference(ps3) for the insured vehicle they destroyed, and they couldnt afford to pay for. (All from personal experience). A way that players can destroy your car, an you have to pay the full premium is using the cargobob to pick your car up an drop it into the ocean, or other bodies of water.